# ViewPager animation outOfMemoryError

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, out-of-memory, android-animation

I have 5 `SlidingTabs`. I want to place `ViewPager` `animation` in one of them.

Fragment class:

```
public class AdFragment extends Fragment {

int[] mResources = {
        R.drawable.six,
        R.drawable.five,
        R.drawable.four,
        R.drawable.eight,
        R.drawable.one,
        R.drawable.two,
        R.drawable.three,
        R.drawable.seven,
        R.drawable.nine,
        R.drawable.ten,
};
int currentPage;
public AdFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}
Timer swipeTimer;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ad, container, false);
    CustomPagerAdapter mCustomPagerAdapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(getActivity(),mResources);

    final ViewPager mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mCustomPagerAdapter);

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final Runnable Update = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (currentPage == mResources.length) {
                currentPage = 0;
            }
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage++, true);
        }
    };

    swipeTimer = new Timer();
    swipeTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(Update);
        }
    }, 500, 3000);

    return view;
}
```

}

Adapter class:

```
class CustomPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

Context mContext;
LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
int[] mResources;
private Resources resource;

public CustomPagerAdapter(Context context,int[] mResources) {
    mContext = context;
    mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.mResources = mResources;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mResources.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == ((LinearLayout) object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    View itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.pager_item, container, false);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    imageView.setImageResource(mResources[position]);

    container.addView(itemView);

    return itemView;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
}
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(View view, int position) {
    ImageView myView = new ImageView(mContext);

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), mResources[position]);
    myView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    ((ViewPager) view).addView(myView);
    return myView;
}
}
```

At the moment I have 10 images in slideshow.When I open my `Tab` with `Fragment` described above, wait for some period, then try to go another `Tab` and back again to this -  I get:

```
    01-27 14:13:53.794 12652-12652/igor.com.totalsoulbeta E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                    Process: igor.com.totalsoulbeta, PID: 12652
                                                                    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
                                                                        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
                                                                        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:587)
                                                                        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:422)
                                                                        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:840)
                                                                        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2113)
                                                                        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:700)
                                                                        at android.content.res.XResources.getDrawable(XResources.java:521)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:323)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.TintManager.getDrawable(TintManager.java:175)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.TintManager.getDrawable(TintManager.java:168)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.setImageResource(AppCompatImageHelper.java:51)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.setImageResource(AppCompatImageView.java:72)
                                                                        at igor.com.totalsoulbeta.CustomPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(CustomPagerAdapter.java:46)
```

The size of each image is not more that 150kb. My  question is: Is it possible to perfome such animation with 25 images without `OutOfMemoryError`? If  yes, what I need to change in my code? How I can clear `heap` and where I need  to do that?
If it's no the best way of animating, please, advise me your variant

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `ViewPager` should be able to show any number of pages. At any time it only has 3 pages in memory (unless you change the offscreen page limit). The probleme may lie with the `Timer` leaking something. The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) says :

> When a timer is no longer needed, users should call cancel(), which
>   releases the timer's thread and other resources. Timers not explicitly
>   cancelled may hold resources indefinitely.

Does it help if you add something like that in the `Fragment` ? :

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();

    swipeTimer.cancel();
    swipeTimer = null;
}
```